# Using typescript plugin with AngularJS ES5 without rewriting entire project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Having an old Ionic v1 project written on AngularJS ES5. How can I use a modern plugin written on JS ES6 without Modernizing entire project?

Comment: Transpile the plugin to ES5 and then import it as a commonjs module.

Comment: @Terry how can I transpile?  Manually once or automatically each build with gulp, webpack?

Comment: It's up to you. If the plugin is from npm you will need to configure webpack to transpile the particular module for you. Otherwise just store a local copy of it that you have manually transpiled, at the expanse of maintainability.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try this out